# PostGIS and connection to QGIS issue?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, qgis

I have a problem with PostGIS and a connection to QGIS. I successfully connected to a database on a server but when I try to add a PostGIS Table, I am getting warning symbols next to all my tables. I have permission to all the tables and I am using the latest version of QGIS.

Any hints?

[image]

Comment: Hover over the warning symbol and you will get to know whats the issue with you data. Possibly you might be missing Geom Column name or DataType or Spatial_type or the Feature_id

Answer (score -1):

@kylie In your database create spatial reference system.
For postgresql----> create extension postgis